# C: Memory usage and problems with Array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, malloc, free

I have two arrays (representing rooms) with items that are traveling through the space. I found an interesting way to allocate the ram here in the forum. Here is what I am doing:
First I create an empty room with some default values. 
After that I put some elements into it. There are two different items. An obstacle and an item that travels through the room. I have an iteration that runs for example 100 times and puts all items one coordinate further. The obstacles keep their position.

Every iteration has to do the following:

First it creates a new temporary room (new_room). It copies all obstacles because they stay at the same place(id = 3). Next, every item from the old room(room) gets his new coordinate in the new_room. After that I change the rooms, so room gets new_room. I have some big problems with the memory usage. I want to free the old new_room every time I create a new one with createRoomNew().In this implementation I get a segmentation fault. I think because of the function changeroom().

I am really confused right now because I am new to C.... I hope I pointed out what I mean. Thank you very much!

```
item_node ***room;
item_node ***room_new;
void createRoom(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if (room == NULL) {
        item_node *allElements = malloc(x * y * z * sizeof(item_node));
        room = malloc(x * sizeof(item_node **));
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            room[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(item_node *));

            for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                room[i][j] = allElements + (i * y * z) + (j * z);
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; j < x_format; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < y_format; k++) {
                for (l = 0; l < z_format; l++) {
                    room[j][k][l].id = 3;
                    room[j][k][l].next = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void createRoomNew(int x, int y, int z)
{
    if (room_new != NULL) {
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            free(room_new[i]);
        }
        free (room_new);
        room_new = NULL;
    }

    if (room_new == NULL) {
        item_node *allElements = malloc(x * y * z * sizeof(item_node));
        room_new = malloc(x * sizeof(item_node **));
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            room_new[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(item_node *));

            for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                room_new[i][j] = allElements + (i * y * z) + (j * z);
            }
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < x_format; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < y_format; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < z_format; l++) {
                if ((room[j][k][l].next) != NULL) {
                    if ((room[j][k][l].next->id) == 1) {
                        room_new[j][k][l] = room[j][k][l];
                    } else {
                        room_new[j][k][l].id = 3;
                        room_new[j][k][l].next = NULL;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    room_new[j][k][l].id = 3;
                    room_new[j][k][l].next = NULL;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
void changeRoom(item_node *** newRoom)
{
    room = newRoom;
}
```

Example call:

```
createRoom(200, 200, 200);
createRoomNew(200, 200, 200);
changeRoom(room_new);
createRoomNew(200, 200, 200);
changeRoom(room_new);
```

Comment: There is no 3D array in your code. Please change the headline and text. Note that being a 3-star programmer in C is not a compliment.

Comment: You should learn to use properly malloc. Try with small examples and debug with `valgrind` (or another memory debugger) in order to know what's going on. Your mallocs are wrong try with a 2D example at first.

Comment: Well, you edited, but you did not get the hint. Please notice that a pointer is not an array and vice versa. Your approach is inefficient. You appear to be requiring just two arrays(!) which are used interchangeably, similar to screenbuffer-flipping for games: draw into the hidden, then swap.

Comment: Hello Olaf, yes i know that but its more about how i imagine it in my mind and how i represent it with the room...the general malloc stuff works, it only gets messed up the second time i use it. I think because of changeRoom. I just wanted to get a little hint about whats actually wrong, maybe with the order.

Answer (score 1):

From the code it seems you think that when you do free, e.g. free(room_new) that room_new ends up being set to NULL. That is not the case

free() doesn't set a pointer to NULL (it can't), it is still pointing to wherever it was pointing just that the memory is no longer usable. You need to manually set the pointer to NULL after freeing.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. I didn't think of that. I am getting a segmentation fault the second time I call createRoomNew() in line 
if ((room[j][k][l].next->id) == 1) {
Do you have any idea why this could occur? Thank you so far!

Comment: In createRoomNew you free room_new but since you do not set it to null afterwards the second if-statement will never execute. When you later try to dereference it,  it will crash.

Comment: Thank you! I added your suggestion but I am still getting the same segfault at the same place...

Comment: In other words: Can you imagine why this occurs the second time I call it? Thank you! :)

Comment: Do you ever set `next`, seems you just set it to NULL. Have you tried a debugger? You have not provided enough code for people to build it and recreate the problem. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: It is hard to troubleshoot when you only see part of the code. You seem also not to have any checks on your global variables e.g. is x_format < x and so on. Lots of possible sources for your segment violation.